# OSMDroid and OpenStreetMapViewItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using in my application OSMDroid. Everything works nice, but not everything is clear.

OpenStreetMapViewItemizedOverlay or (OpenStreetMapViewItemizedOverlayWithFocus) will be used.

If the user clicks on an item from this overlay, a small pop-up occurs with item's title
and description.

Does anybody know, how to implement click-listener if the user clicks
on that pop-up?

I haven't found any methods for that and I'll be very thankfull for
any suggestion or link.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know OSMDroid uses same API as google. Google's `ItemizedOverlay` has two methods `onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)` and `onTap(int index)` which both

> "handle a "tap" on an item"

and must be overwritten.

Have a look here: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html

Comment: I can click on items, that is no problem. The problem is, that I cann't (or better to say I couldn't) click on toolbars with description.

Comment: @M.E. Is there a similar way to detect a click on a DirectedLocationOverlay marker? I tried to override public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(final MotionEvent e, final MapView mapView) but it just seems to detect a tap anywhere on the map, not just on the marker.